# How to serialize model fields related through foreign key?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to serialize the name field from Bank Model in BranchSerializer. The id field is a foreign key in the branch model.

I have tried RelatedField :

```
class BankSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bank


class BranchSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    bank_name = serializers.RelatedField(source=Bank, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = ('ifsc', 'branch', 'address', 'city', 'district', 'state', 'bank_name')
```

Model:

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'banks'
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


bank = Bank()


class Branch(models.Model):
    ifsc = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, primary_key=True)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'branches'
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.branch, bank.name)
```

Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from records.models import Bank, Branch


class BankSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bank


class BranchSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    bank_name = serializers.RelatedField(source=Bank, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = ('ifsc', 'branch', 'address', 'city', 'district', 'state', 'bank_name')
```

```
TypeError: argument of type 'ModelBase' is not iterable
```

Comment: you can use a `CharField` like this: `bank_name = serializers.CharField(source='bank.name', read_only=True)`

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot for the help.